# ASP.NET Framework - How to resolve System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, httpclient

I have an old project in ASP.NET Framework-4.8, I am given this API to consume. It is a POST Request, with JSON Request and Response. I want to consume the API using HttpClient POST Request.

URL:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="PostTransactionUrl" value="https://thirdpartyapi/PostEntries"/>
</appSettings>
```

I got this error::

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\runtime\exceptionservices\exceptionservicescommon.cs:line 133
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\runtime\compilerservices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line 156


  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(System.IAsyncResult) in _TLSstream.cs
    System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(System.IAsyncResult) in _ConnectStream.cs

Inner Exception 1:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

Inner Exception 2:
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

When I debugged and checked the Log, it points at:

```
var apiResponse = PostAccountBalanceRequestUrl(apiBaseAccountUrl, requestDto).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and

```
var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Kindly help resolve the error

MAIN CODE:

Service Layer:

```
private string apiBaseAccountUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PostTransactionUrl"];

private Lazy<HttpClient> http = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
    //Handle TLS protocols
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
        System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
        | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
        | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };

    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    return client;
});

private async Task<AccountBalanceResponseDto> PostAccountBalanceRequestUrl(string baseUrl, AccountBalanceRequestDto requestDto)
{
    var client = http.Value;

    // Serialize the request object to JSON
    var jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestDto);
    var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUrl, content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response1 = response;
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountBalanceResponseDto>(resp);
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

[WebMethod]
public AccountBalanceResponse AccountBalanceRequest(String AccountNumber)
{
    AccountNumber = Server.HtmlEncode(AccountNumber).AlphaNumeric();

    AccountBalanceResponse resp = new AccountBalanceResponse();
    try
    {
        var requestDto = new AccountBalanceRequestDto()
        {
            customer_acc_no = AccountNumber
        };

        var apiResponse = PostAccountBalanceRequestUrl(apiBaseAccountUrl, requestDto).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if(apiResponse != null)
        {
            if (apiResponse.fcubsheader.msgstat == "SUCCESS")
            {
                resp.ResponseCode = "00";
                resp.ResponseText = "SUCCESS";
                resp.AccountName = apiResponse.acdesc;
                resp.Amount = Convert.ToDecimal(apiResponse.acyavlbal);
                resp.BalanceDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                resp.Currency = apiResponse.ccy;
            }
            else
            {
       resp.ResponseText = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            resp.ResponseText = ex.Message;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        resp.ResponseText = ex.Message;
        return resp;
    }
    return resp;
```

Comment: The error really says it all: *The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.* - and as long as the remote server has an invalid certificate, you will not be able to establish an `https://` connection to it. Nothing much you can do on your end - the API provider needs to clean up his act!